# NetCDF: Not a valid data type or _FillValue type mismatch

Tags: cygwin, netcdf, cdo-climate

I'm using `cdo` on cygwin to pre-process some CMIP6 simulations, in netcdf format.

I just got the message error for the CESM2 model :

```
NetCDF: Not a valid data type or _FillValue type mismatch
```

I never got this message error before, with other models

I am tring to convert into netcdf classic my file :

```
nccopy -k 'classic' in.nc out.nc
```

and then apply the cdo command lines remapbil and detrend.

Another option would be to download the OpenDAP file, and then to convert them in netcdf, but I do not now how to do that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: any chance to give us the output of ncdump  -h on the file so we can see the header and metadata?

Answer (score 1):

As you have said in the question it is probably easier to work with the OpenDAP files. To do this all you need to is search [ESGF](https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/search/cmip6/) for what you want. Get the url from "OpenDAP Download", remove the ".dods" from it, so it ends with ".nc". If you then want to use it with CDO you would just do something like the following:

```
cdo seltimestep,1 http://esgf-data.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/esg_dataroot/CMIP6/CMIP/NCAR/CESM2/amip/r2i1p1f1/Amon/tas/gn/v20190220/tas_Amon_CESM2_amip_r2i1p1f1_gn_195001-201412.nc test.nc
```

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin Netcdf libraries are for NETCDF 4.

```
$ cygcheck cdo |grep netcdf
    D:\cygwin64\bin\cygnetcdf-19.dll

$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/cygnetcdf-19.dll
libnetcdf19-4.8.1-1
```

NETCDF Classic is version 3

https://www.earthdata.nasa.gov/esdis/esco/standards-and-references/netcdf-classic

Have you the data available in format 4 ?